# Validate form ip formation in html forms

Tags: html, forms, validation, ip

I have a form that receive ip address from user and i wanna to if ip which user inserts isn't match with ip formation like 192.168.0.100(*.*._._)it will show error.how can i do that?

```
 <form name="add" >
 <input name="ip" type="text" value="" />  
 <button name="submit" type="submit" value="">
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Split string by point and first three parts must be equals and other must be positive number less then 255

Comment: you want ta make validation on server or on client side?